# Show all specified div elements only on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have the following jquery code that automatically leaves the first div in my page expanded. I would like each div to be closed until the user clicks on that div. Can an update please be suggested to ensure these are all closed until the user clicks?

**CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").slice(1).hide();//expands first FAQ content
    $(".expand_heading:first").addClass("active");//add active class to first FAQ title
    $("h4.expand_heading").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        $(this).toggleClass("");
        $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your HTML

Comment: Does the active class handle the display/show hide state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove [`slice(1)`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to include the first element while hiding and also the line [`$(".expand_heading:first").addClass("active")`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) since you don't want to set the first one as active.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".toggle_container").hide();//expands first FAQ content
    $("h4.expand_heading").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        $(this).toggleClass("");
        $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```